# SQL filled Droplist does not refresh values on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

[image]

So here in my application I have 2 dropdowns, 4 labels and a gridview. The `Medication Type` drop list here with the text `PO Meds` is supposed to generate the number you see between the 2 drop lists, then based on that number, pull all of the records in the medications table with that number as an ID. The medications should populate in the dropdown marked `Medication`. The first time I run the application it pulls up the correct information but if I try changing that information, instead of the medication dropdown refilling with the new query information it just adds it to the medication droplist.

here are my 2 droplist and code:

***HTML***

```
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMedType" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsMedType" DataTextField="MedType" DataValueField="MedType" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMedType_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select Medication Type</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsMedType" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SiteSqlServer2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [num], [MedType] FROM [pharm_medication_Type]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMedType" runat="server" Visible="true"/>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMedication" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMedication_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Choose A Medication</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

***.CS***

```
protected void ddlMedType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strMedType = ddlMedType.SelectedValue;
        using (SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer2"].ConnectionString))
        {
            if (ddlMedType.SelectedValue != "Select Medication Type")
            {
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT [num] from [pharm_medication_Type] where [MedType] = @MedType", conn1);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MedType", strMedType);
                conn1.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader2.Read())
                    {
                        int strNum = reader2.GetInt32(0);
                        lblMedType.Text = Convert.ToString(strNum);

                    }
                }

                string strMedTypeID = lblMedType.Text;
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select [MedType_ID], [MedName] from [pharm_medications] where [MedType_ID] = @MedTypeID", conn1);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MedTypeID", strMedTypeID);
                ddlMedication.DataSource = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                lblMedType.Text = string.Empty;
                ddlMedication.DataTextField = "MedName";
                ddlMedication.DataValueField = "MedName";
                ddlMedication.DataBind();
                ddlMedType.DataBind();
                lblMedType.DataBind();

            }
        }            
    }

    protected void ddlMedication_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strMedTypeID = lblMedType.Text;
        string strMedName = ddlMedication.SelectedValue;
        if (ddlMedication.SelectedValue != "Choose A Medication")
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer2"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT DISTINCT [num], [MedType_ID], [MedName], [MedMin], [MedMax], [ChargingNumber] 
                                                FROM [pharm_medications] WHERE [MedType_ID] = @MedTypeID AND [MedName] = @MedName", conn1);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MedTypeID", strMedTypeID);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MedName", strMedName);
                conn1.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader3 = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader3.Read())
                    {
                        int myNum = reader3.GetInt32(0);
                        int strMyMedTypeID = reader3.GetInt32(1);
                        string strMyMedName = reader3.GetString(2);
                        string strMedMin = reader3.GetString(3);
                        string strMedMax = reader3.GetString(4);
                        string strChargingNumber = reader3.GetString(5);
                        lblAutoMin.Text = strMedMin;
                        lblAutoMax.Text = strMedMax;
                        lblAutoChargeNum.Text = strChargingNumber;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Just add `ddlMedication.Clear();` before `ddlMedication.DataTextField = "MedName";`